# Overflow Functionality Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, css, overflow

Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem I have:

http://www.turdidesigns.com/bin/ebay/antic_arte/cabecero.html

Open it with Explorer and you will notice the movement in the menu, I don't want it, I need it to funcion as in chrome.

Sorry for such question, but I'm stuck...

I want to make a hover with css, so in general the text is hidden, but when hovered the text appears below. The overflow method is working good in chrome, but I can't make it work in IE.

P.s. Can't use any javascript's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why was it closed? The question seems clear for me...

Comment: I don't know... I tryed to explain it as I could, I suppose because of my english, I can't express myself correctly. Well... It's sad. Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: it's just some people showing off that they have voting rights.

Comment: I worked hard to ask this question, posted the files online modified the original CSS etc... And lost reputation... awesome ! At least got an answer. Thanks Oriol !

Comment: Voted for reopen, but it'll need 4 more votes... EDIT: OK, your original title was FULL CAPS, that surely pissed off 5 people or more. Did you see another title FULL CAPS? No? Then don't do that either ;)

Comment: Ups, I didn't think of that Felipe. Either way, sorry !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On firefox it doesn't work either.

The followinf code worked for me on Firefox:

```
#navi li {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

But then you need

```
#navi {
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

instead of `45px`

Why do you have your page inside a table which has only one cell? You should avoid using tables, but in your case it seems nonsense.

Comment: I'm preparing a template for ebay, so I use tables.